# Should I use 'infintive' or 'gerund' after pronouns?

Tags: pronouns, infinitive-vs-gerund

> Her father opposed to her **marrying** a foreigner

In the above sentence it's used a gerund 'marrying' after the pronoun 'her'. What if I use a infinitive verb instead of using a 'gerund' as;

> Her father opposed to her **to marry** a foreigner

Is there any exceptions not to use infinitives after pronouns in such sentences or are these sentences having different meaning?

Comment: Neither is correct. The problem is the preposition "to". But you can say  or "Her father opposed her marrying a foreigner", or with an object, "Her father opposed her marriage to a foreigner".

Comment: Also (if it helps) "Are there any exceptions to using infinitives...".

Answer (score 4):

> Her father opposed her marrying a foreigner. ✓

Source: [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/oppose)

Some verbs are followed by a gerund, some with a to-infinitive, and some with either. The best way to make sure which to use is check in a good dictionary.

Comment: I have a question with the sentence "*The best way to make sure which to use is check in a good dictionary*." Why don't you put "...which to use is *to* check in a good dictionary"

Comment: @dan: Both are correct. If fact there's an implicit "to" before "check", e.g. All you need to do is (to) sleep more = To sleep more is all you need to do.